# Stop Webcam in React Component in ComponentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that starts a webcam when a component called VideoPage is mounted.

However, when I navigate to another page, the webcam is still running in the background. I know this because the webcam activity light is still activated on my laptop.

I believe I will to 'kill' the webcam in the React lifecycle method ComponentWillUnmount when the component unmounts. How can I achieve that?

My code is below. I appreciate the advice. Thanks!

import React from "react";

```
export default class VideoPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.videoTag = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then(this.handleStream)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  handleStream = async stream => {
    // start receiving stream from webcam
    this.videoTag.current.srcObject = stream;

    console.log("The video is ready");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
          <video
            id="myvideo"
            ref={this.videoTag}
            width={426}
            height={240}
            autoPlay
            title="video"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stop a getUserMedia request, you need to call the [`stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop) method of the [MediaStreamTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop) it generated.
To access these MediaStreamTracks, you need to call the [`getTracks()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/getTracks) method of the `stream` MediaStream you received in your `handleStream` method.

So it would be good to save your stream somewhere in your instance, e.g as `this.stream`.
Then in your `componentWillUnmount`, you will call

```
this.stream.getTracks()
  .forEach((track) => track.stop());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kalido answer, my final working code is as below...

Here's a link to a github repo with my solution... [Github Repo](https://github.com/myhendry/lab-mongo/blob/master/web-js/src/modules/ml5/featureExtractor_regression/FeRegressionPage.jsx)

```
  constructor(props) {
    // set up constructor
    super(props);

    // create video ref
    this.videoTag = React.createRef();
    this.myStream = null;

    // set up initial state
    this.state = {
      guess: "",
      probability: null,
      loading: false,
      scale: defaultValue
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // set up webcam when component mounting
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: true })
      .then(this.handleStream)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.myStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  }

  handleStream = async stream => {
    this.myStream = stream;

    // start receiving stream from webcam
    this.videoTag.current.srcObject = stream;

    // prepare classifier and assign myClassifier in global scope
    myClassifier = await this.prepareClassifier(this.videoTag.current);
    console.log(myClassifier);
    console.log("The video is ready");
  };
```